# Locked out by XScreenSaver

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver

In my Ubuntu 13.04, I suddenly found that though I can login, I am immediately blocked by XScreenSaver. So, I can no longer get into my account.

I do have the root  password if needed, and can get into another account.

How do I disable/remove XScreenSaver?

Comment: Is the other account in the admin group? That means, can you use `sudo` with this account?

Comment: I think so. But I can't get into it.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 and you can login...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Execute this command to remove Xscreensaver**

```
sudo apt-get autoremove xscreensaver
sudo apt-get --purge remove xscreensaver
```

**To disable, you've to go to:**

**in gnome**

```
system->preferences->Sessions->Startup Programs
```

and delete the entry of **xscreensaver**.

<sub>Also give a look at **`System -> Preferences -> Screensaver`**</sub>

**in Unity**

Search `Brightness and Lock` in dash, and just click <kbd>Off</kbd> under **Lock**, you can set configurations according to your need.

**More help**

```
man xscreensaver
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try removing xscreensaver. However, I can't disable it (in Lubuntu), because it is locking me out!

Comment: I didn't know you were using Lubuntu. For Lubuntu, I really don't know how to disable. :( Although I'll try my best to find the way to disable.

Comment: Thanks,  removin xscreensaver, after logging into another account, did it.